# API Design: Global Variable vs Passing the object around

Tags: api, design-patterns, static, global-variables, facade

I am maintaining a legacy SDK. The SDK will behave differently for different platform. It's using a static variable and requires the static variable to be created before any API call like the following:

Example for static global variable (OLD CODE):

```
SDKContext.init();
VideoManager manager = new VideoManager();
public void VideoManager#search() {
    SDKContext.search();
}
```

Components like VideoManager are all over the place. My gut feeling tells me I should use local variable instead, but can't be sure.

Local Variable(MY PREFERRED WAY):

```
SDKContext context = new SDKContext();
// Or even using singleton
SDKContext context = SDKContext.getInstance();
VideoManager manager = new VideoManager(context);
public void VideoManager#search() {
     context.search();
}
```

What's the pros and cons these two approaches? Any recommendation/suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call it a FACADE.

Facade is, compared to normal approach, simplified version of API, covering more complex operations underneath. In you case API of `VideoManager#search()` in both cases - the one you call not-facade, and the one that you claim to be a facade - is exactly the same. Moreover, method body is nearly the same too. Replacing global variable with object does not have anything common with being a facade, it's just a decision you can make during the implementation.

Global variable (or singleton) can simplify your code (in such case, where you need to pass it around to a lot of places, it can be worth of give it a try), at cost of harder testing (mocking) it - the decision is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Statics make unit testing difficult.

Approach 2 is much better. It's IoC-friendly and easily testable.

Answer (score 0):

You could give some IoC container a try. I will make for you the "singleton" and some of them have even "auto-wiring".